# How to club the common elements of the index in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
           type count
batsman         
V Kohli     4   361
V Kohli     6   149
SK Raina    5   1
SK Raina    6   161
RG Sharma   5   1
RG Sharma   6   164
```

Now we can see that there are commmon entries in the index. I want to plot a **barh plot**, so i want to club the index into one so that the dataframe looks something like this:

```
            type count
batsman         
V Kohli     4   361
            6   149
SK Raina    5   1
            6   161
RG Sharma   5   1
            6   164
```

How do i do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _clubbing_ the index? What are the index values going to be for the blank rows?

Comment: There are no blank rows

Comment: Blank rows in the index, I meant.

Comment: I actually want to set a single common index for all the type of runs for a single batsman. So that I can plot a barh graph. Something like a groupby

Comment: I added an answer below with what I think you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the index to a new column and do a groupby.

```
df['batsman'] = df.index
grouped_df = df.groupby(['batsman', 'type']).agg({'count': 'sum'})
# grouped_df

           type count
batsman         
V Kohli     4   361
            6   149
SK Raina    5   1
            6   161
RG Sharma   5   1
            6   164
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your DataFrame's index and "type" column then aggregate to get a reasonable grouped output in your barh plot.

```
df.groupby([df.index,'type'])['count'].sum().plot.barh(title='Counts')
```

[image]